# Unable to create NSUUID with initWithUUIDString

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, crash

Maybe I am missing something fundamental, but I can't even create a NSUUID for iOS 6/7 at all.

I tried something like

```
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID alloc] ;
[uuid initWithUUIDString:@"bec26202-a8d8-4a94-80fc-9ac1de37daa6"];
```

put at the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of my application, and run on an actual iPhone, I got an

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x18cb76be3)

error, and of course the application crashes.

I even tried another approach

```
NSUUID * nsuuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
```

which also crashes.

I downloaded the [Airdrop example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013842), which at some point uses the code

```
NSString * _filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"profile-%@.customprofile", [[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(24, 12)]];
```

Although in the demo it runs fine, when I copy this code to my own, it crashes again.

So... I am stuck... any ideas?

Comment: does it crash (and Xcode stop) on those lines, or does it crash when you try to access "`uuid`" or the "`nsuuid`" objects?

Comment: Also, what happens when you try "`UIDevice * currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice]; NSUUID *nsuuid = currentDevice.identifierForVendor;`"?

Comment: i tried your codes for generating UUID on my device, didn't crash for me. I guess that's not the part causing the crash.

Comment: It crashes exactly when calling the [uuid init...] part. It seems like it doesn't like being "init"ialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code you posted to generate UUID but I didn't get a crash. The crash is probably caused by something else in your code. In Xcode, go to the Breakpoint Navigator, and add All Exceptions. It will breakpoint at your code at where it finds an exception.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a NSUUID string just do the following...

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to close this thread, I found the problem.
Thank you all guys for the help.

The problem was with some code that was overriding the "init" selector of NSUUID through categories and didn't properly return "self".

Thus, although "alloc" worked, any kind of "init" didn't.